# Autenticação de Múltiplos models no Django

Tags: django

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com Django 3, nela tenho o model candidato e o model empresa que possuem login e senha como campos. A ideia é que o model candidato e o model empresa possa autenticar utilizando as classes de autenticação do Django( Django authentication system) para fazer as validações e autenticação. É possível utilizar as classes para mais de uma model? Caso contrário, qual seria a melhor solução?

Comment: Sem olhar para o teu models.py, umas vez que não partilhaste código. Eu diria que podes utilizar com classe abstracta. Contudo, porque não utilizas tudo no mesmo model? Adicionas um tipo, candidato e empresa, e seria sempre o mesmo.

Comment: Isso mesmo, encontrei [aqui](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html) o que preciso. Obrigado.